# Rough idling, car stalling in cold, won't start at all after filled up with fuel?

Tags: stall, rough-idle, oil-pressure, cold, oil-pressure-sensor

Having a bit of an issue with my 2009 Nissan Pixo - the car stalls intermittently after it's just been started up (it's fine after it has been running for a while though), and it won't start at all without pressing the gas pedal after it's just been filled up with fuel. In both cases, the oil pressure warning light turns on, and everything loses power.

The intermittent stalling only really happens when it's quite cold outside, and when coming to a stop, and the car also idles rough. I've tried putting in some fuel treatment, which seemed to make things a bit better, but the problem still persists.

I've taken it to a mechanic, but because the problem is intermittent, they've had trouble finding the fault.

Anyone got any idea what the problem could be? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean "It won't start at all without . . . just been filled up with fuel"? Do you have a supply of gasoline, and it only starts when you top it off?

Answer (score 1):

I think your oil issue is coincidental -  My money is on a faulty/dirty mass air flow sensor, or a leak in your intake assembly causing bad readings on the sensor.

Examine your intake assembly from filter to throttle body - make sure there is no "unregulated air" seeping in from loose connections. All air must pass through the mass air flow sensor for the ECM to know the proper air/fuel ratio. Where the intake tubing meets the throttle body is suspect.

This problem is exacerbated in the cold, as the air is more oxygen rich - a small amount of unregulated air can cause more of a problem.

If your vehicle *knows* that it's cold, it can compensate - but the mass air flow sensor needs to be working properly. It should be located somewhere on the intake assembly, with a pigtail/wires sticking out. Make sure it's clean and oriented properly, as per your vehicle manufacturers specifications.

Comment: I agree with the *"oil issue is coincidental"*. Oil pumps are mechanical, so if the RPMs begin to drop (below the normal idle level), the oil pressure will momentarily drop as well. This is probably causing the oil pressure warning light to come on. This happens sometimes as I am (accidentally) causing my manual Ram 1500 to stall.

Comment: Regarding the Mass AirFlow (MAF) sensor: try unplugging it and take the car for a drive. This will cause the check engine light to turn on, but it will also make the car use a "default" air-fuel mixture, instead of constantly altering the air-fuel mixture based on how much air the MAF sensor is detecting. If the stalling problem ceases, then your problem is either a faulty MAF sensor, or as Aww_Geez mentioned, you have air leaking in *after* the MAF.